# Can't compile .tex file after MacTeX 2017 last packages update

Tags: graphics, tcolorbox, mactex, updating

Till last update of MacTeX my files were compiled nice.
After update I can't compile them. Example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[overwrite=true]{getmap}
\usepackage{calc}


\usepackage[unicode,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry} % Меняем поля страницы
\geometry{left=1.5cm}% левое поле
\geometry{right=1.5cm}% правое поле
\geometry{top=1.5cm}% верхнее поле
\geometry{bottom=1.5cm}% нижнее поле


\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{=}

Hello world

\begin{tcolorbox}[sharpish corners,colframe=gray,title={\textbf{* Attention}}]
Bla Bla Bla Bla
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

After starting of the compilation process stops with this message:

> Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty)
>   (./protex.aux)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
>   [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
>   /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii:175:
>
> Mis sing number, treated as zero.
>
> \let
>   l.175 \unprotect
>
> ?

Compilation finishes well only if lines `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\usepackage{tcolorbox}` commented.
Could you help, please?

Comment: The compilation fails on TL 2017 on Linux too, but I suspect `babel` here

Comment: But it is connected to `tcolorbox` as well

Comment: @ChristianHupfer no tcolorbox is the problem. It is a clash between turkish and graphics.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The error occurs also by commenting `graphicx` out and keeping `tcolorbox`, the later does not load `graphicx`, so either it is `tcolorbox` in addition or some other package that does load `graphicx` ... just checked: It's `tcolorbox` and its chain-loading of other packages downto `graphicx`

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I use `\begin{document} 
\shorthandoff{=}` for `turkish` goes well with `graphicx`

Comment: The problem is with supp-pdf.mkii. It doesn't like the active = from turkish. You can avoid the error by loading graphicx before babel.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Works fine now. Great! Thanks!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to answer?